# Unused Local Variables (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, compiler-warnings, unused-variables

I'm ridding my code of all compiler warnings, as per my bosses request, when I came across some unused local variables. Naturally, I removed the ones which were legitimate, however I stumbled upon a couple which aren't as straight forward. (Variable names changed for security)

```
Dim strAAA As String = "aaaa" & strBBB & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".doc"
If FUNCTION_NAME(strCCCC, strAAA) Then Return True
```

strAAA is allegedly an 'unused local variable' when it is clearly used directly below.

Even when I write it as follows:

```
Dim strAAA As String 
strAAA = "ViewLet" & strBBB & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".doc"
If FUNCTION_NAME(strTmpFileName, strAAA) Then Return True
```

The warning is still present.

Can anybody solve this mystery?

Comment: Have you tried ["turning it off and on again"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nn2FB1P_Mn8)?

Comment: Probably there's some other error somewhere that is generating what you're seeying. Without seeing the complete code/and error message I doubt anyone will be able to help.

Comment: I've found that if it is compiled  with the warning active then later change it, the warning stays until it is re-compiled.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - First thing I tried (after the obvious)

Comment: @bastos.sergio - All errors have been eradicated, leaving only this and other unused local variable warnings. This one is the first in the list.

Comment: @tinstaafl - I tried changing the unused local variable option to 'none', recompiling, setting back to warning and recompiling to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried a Clean and then a Rebuild?  If that doesn't work, try deleting your bin and obj folders and then build it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it.
There was a `Return True` about 50 lines above.
This was always being hit, thus the variables were never being set.

Sloppy code from my predecessor I'm afraid!

Comment: Insult to injury: The blasted function wasn't even getting called!

Comment: Re: "function wasn't even getting called" - you might be interested in using [FxCop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6544) to have a check over your code. Or your version of VS might have the code analysis tools built in.

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating the variable instance...

```
If FUNCTION_NAME(strTmpFileName, "ViewLet" & strBBB & Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".doc") Then Return True
```